# How can I have 'Next homescreen' and 'Previous homescreen' buttons in ADW EX on the dockbar like LauncherPro?

Tags: adw.launcher

I'm using ADW EX (purchased in the recent 10 billion, 10 day sale). How can I have buttons for next homescreen and previous homescreen on the bottom dockbar like in LauncherPro Plus?

Currently using ADW 1.3.3.56

Comment: I'm not sure that this functionality exists, unfortunately. It does have launcher actions/icons that take you directly to any screen (i.e. if you have 5 screens you can put a "Screen 4" icon somewhere to jump straight to it).

Comment: Dang ! Seems a rather basic feature to have, doesn't it?

Comment: Would it be easier to use than swiping?

Comment: Personal preference, I guess. Mustn't be a very "wanted" feature judging by the fact that it's not available in newer launchers like Apex and Nova too.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been asked a while ago, but on the CyanogenMod 7 version of ADW, you have to go in ui settings, then set the dock size to 3 or less and enable "Desktop dots". I think there's similar option on the original version...

Comment: What version of CM? CM9 uses trebuchet by default.

Comment: CM7 sorry, forgot to mention it.